# my jquery won't work

Tags: jquery

I hate asking a stupid question like this, but I can't seem to get the jquery to run.  I have it all working in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3FTRE/1/  but when I bring it over to my site it isn't woring. Here is the code so you can see that it is the same.

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#info').keyup(function(){
        $('.info').html($(this).val());
    });

    $('#company').keyup(function(){
        $('.company').html($(this).val());
    });

    $('#info').keyup(function () {
        var left = 170 - $(this).val().length;
        if (left < 0) {
            left = 0;
        }
        $('#counter').text('Characters left: ' + left);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

I have been using fire bug to try and diagnose the problem and all it says is "$ is not defined."

I literally copy and pasted everything to my program and it won't work.  Would love help figuring out what the problem is.  Thanks for the help!

added an image of the NET as recomended

[image]

Comment: View source and check where query lib is adding in the source

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: I am connected to the internet :-)

Comment: You haven't answered whether the browser dev tools show if the jQuery script has loaded correctly or not, and there's not enough information here to diagnose what the problem might be, especially without seeing the page that doesn't work. I'll have to vote to close as "too localized" for now.

Comment: I assume it's this page: http://coolefitness.com/sponsor.php ? You don't have a line that would load jQuery anywhere on that page.

Comment: @TimCooley Can you add a screenshot of your script tab.

Comment: Got it to work . . .  It had something to do with the FTP and media temple not uploading my changes.  Thanks for the help!  I will have to ask them why this happens.

Comment: seems like to be an april fool.

Answer (score 0):

$ not defined normaly means that JQuery has not been loaded correctly. Under firebug select the net tab. Does it show the JQuery lib as loading correctly? Also why are you loading it twice?

Comment: I added the img of the NET interface

Comment: Thanks for the help.  There was an issue with my hosting and FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below for jquery library reference.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

If you are using IE debugger go to script tab and verify all your js are properly loaded. Also make sure this library reference is at top of all js reference.

[image]

Comment: @wumm if you read my sentence carefully you would understand what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

eYour problem is you are double loading jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remove one of those lines then it should works

Comment: I removed one of them and no luck.